# Xamarin.Android when startup tracing is enabled, app cannot be deployed (NDK MISSING)

Tags: xamarin.android

I am tring to speed up the launch of my xamarin.android app (forms).

But after it has compilied it says:

```
 Could not locate the Android NDK. Please make sure the Android NDK is installed in the Android SDK Manager, or if using a custom NDK path, please ensure the $(AndroidNdkDirectory) MSBuild property is set to the custom path.
```

But only with startup tracing enabled. Taking it out, and everything works again.

How is that possible?

Best,

J

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: There is hardly any code involved...

Answer (score 0):

Here are several workarounds for this issue:

- You can set your Android NDK locations here is a document about it
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/android-sdk-location?tabs=windows
- If you cannot change the default location of the Android NDK through the settings,
  make sure you installed NDK, if not: **Tools > Android > Android SDK manager > Tools > select NDK > Apply Changes**
  and
  **Create a folder named "AndroidNDK64" in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft**
  then Move the **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk**... folder to the folder you just created

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2022 doesn't have the Android NDK Location field that's in the screenshot on the android-sdk-location page you linked (maybe other versions do.) My android csproj file has "<AndroidNdkDirectory>$(AndroidSdk)/ndk-bundle</AndroidNdkDirectory>" under the project property group. The NDKs are installing into that folder, and I've attempted to replace "AndroidSdk" with the full path to the same folder. I am still getting the same NDK missing error.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue I had to uninstall the NDK, and install the latest Side by Side NDK.
This is done by doing the following in Visual Studio Community 2022:

- Open the Android SDK Manager via Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager
- Tools tab
- Expand NDK and de-select the installed NDK (if any)
- Expand Other. If Other is not visible, click the Great icon (options,) Repository, and select Full List.
- Within Other, select the latest NDK (Side by side) option. I selected the latest 4 versions on a whim.
- Click Apply Changes to uninstall the old NDK and install the NDK (Side by side) versions you've selected.

After doing this, I was able to deploy to my device with the Startup Tracing build option enabled.